# iOS -- persuade an NSOperation to yield to other threads before starting a long and apparently unbreakable task?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, pdf, nsoperation

I have a low-priority PDF-drawing NSOperation.  I am using the function CGContextDrawPDFPage to draw the page.

As best I can tell, the app will not switch to another thread while the CGContextDrawPDFPage function is executing.  I suppose I need to break up my graphics context into several smaller contexts to get around that.  But I still have one problem -- how can I persuade the operation to allow other threads to perform their tasks before starting that draw?  The way things are set up right now, the app draws the page right away, even though the thread priority is set to zero.

Here is the code that adds the NSOperation to the queue:

```
MyNSOperationSubclass* op = [[MyNSOperationSubclass alloc]initWithStuff: stuff];
[op setThreadPriority:0.];
[self.drawingQueue addOperation:op];
```

Here is some code within MyNSOperationSubclass:

```
-(void) drawStuff {
    NSLog(@"drawStuff");
    @autoreleasepool {
        // some code to setup the graphics context and PDF page here
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
        [self finish];  // finishes the NSOperation
    }   
}

-(void) main {
    NSLog(@"main");
    @autoreleasepool {
        [self drawStuff];
    }

}

-(void) start {
    self.isExecuting = YES;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

what happens is that even though the thread priority is set to zero, the setup code is so quick that the NSOperation gets into the CGContextDrawPDFPage call right as the operation is started.  But  once that call has started, the thread won't yield to other threads until it has finished.  So the drawing operation happens right away, which is the opposite of what I want to do.

EDIT:  After taking a closer look, the first answerer is correct that the CGContextDrawPDFPage call does not always prevent a thread from yielding.  But even with a non-concurrent operation, I still have the problem that it finishes quickly, rather than waiting around for other, higher-priority stuff to happen.

EDIT 2:  Apparently I don't understand how thread priorities work.  After changing it to a nonconcurrent operation, the thread priority of the operation thread is 0.5, even though I called [op setThreadPriority: 0] before adding it to the queue.

Comment: I am using `CGContextDrawPDFPage` in my production and I can assure you that thread-context switching can occur during the call.

Comment: You are right.  See my edits above.

Comment: You forgot to call `[super start]`, which is apparently the method that set the thread priority accordingly. Search for 'Changing the Underlying Thread Priority' in the System Guides for more information.

Comment: What is the nature of this other "high priority stuff" and how is that work being scheduled. Do you want these other work items to finish before this PDF is created? How do you know the other work isn't blocking for other reasons?

Comment: I want the new screen to render.  The PDF is a background job in case the user goes there next.

Answer (score 2):

So, the first thought is that your thread can't avoid "yielding" to other threads. Context switching is pre-emptive here. So you might want to talk about why you think this thread is not yielding. You may have some other bigger issue here with the other work that you are expecting to be done.

Second, when you set the thread priority for this operation, you're not setting the priority of this new thread that you are creating yourself here:

`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self withObject:nil];`

That's a new thread with normal priority.

But stepping back from that a second, why not just make this a non-concurrent operation and let your NSOperationQueue manage the thread for you? The queue will create a new thread for you as needed (and apply your thread priority that you asked for).

Alternatively, unless you still need to support iOS3, you can just use the global low priority GCD queue for this work (or target your own GCD queue to that global queue if you need finer control over order and still want all of this done with low priority).

So, consider letting either NSOperationQueue or GCD manage some of this for you. And think about **why** you think this thread is interfering with other work. That's probably some bigger issue.

Hope that helps.